# PHP Regular expression : Convert string to anchor

Tags: php, regex

I have strings that looks like this example:

```
$str = "Sally sells [[seashells]] by the [[seashore]]."
```

I need to convert strings like the above to:

```
Sally sells <a href='?action=definition&word=seashells'>seashells</a> by the <a href='?action=definition&word=seashore'>seashore</a>.
```

Please note how the word between the square brackets is used in the anchor tag.

can anyone give me direction to solve this ?

Comment: I tried with different regular expressions, but couldn't sort out this

Comment: these might help for the future: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html, http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$pattern = "/\[\[([\w-]+)\]\]/";
$replace = "<a href='?action=definition&word=$1'>$1</a>";
$msg = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $msg);
```

[**See it in action here.**](http://regexr.com?36iri)

Note that the token that's searched for within the brackets, `[\w-]+`, will only match the letters `A-Z` (case insensitive), digits `0-9`, hyphens `-`, and underscores `_`. Allowing too many other types of characters might mean having to use `urlencode` on the matches as an additional step.